# DAC gives timeout and fails to start the isolated environment with a silent setupper

Tags: desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

Any ideas how to fix this timeout issue?
My application setupper is 100% silent, when I run it by hand, so the setupper itself is not hanging...

> [2016-09-27T16:50:57] Log file can be found in
>   C:\DesktopAppConverter\4e2c2695-d2df-4384-b4e7-27b2a8f5e93d\logs\DesktopAppConverter.log
>   [2016-09-27T16:50:57] Desktop App Converter
>   1.0.0.release_2016-09-12_17-35_ffbf3b5cdc49b01e13ab503dae648326acae0991
>
> ### [2016-09-27T16:50:57]
>
> Checking Prerequisites
>
> [2016-09-27T16:50:57] Checking Windows Version to ensure it meets
>   minimum requirements [2016-09-27T16:50:57] Minimum Windows Version
>   requirement is met. [2016-09-27T16:50:57] Testing for required feature
>   enabled... [2016-09-27T16:51:00] Required feature is enabled. Checking
>   if reboot is required [2016-09-27T16:51:03] Required feature is
>   enabled. [2016-09-27T16:51:03] Checking network config...
>   [2016-09-27T16:51:03] Checking virtual network: "Windows Desktop App
>   Converter Network" [2016-09-27T16:51:03] Using virtual network:
>   "Windows Desktop App Converter Network" [2016-09-27T16:51:03] Checking
>   if Microsoft Windows 10 SDK is installed [2016-09-27T16:51:03]
>   Checking if MAKEAPPX.exe is available in the Microsoft Windows 10 SDK
>   tools [2016-09-27T16:51:03] Checking if SIGNTOOL.exe is available in
>   the Microsoft Windows 10 SDK tools [2016-09-27T16:51:03] Checking
>   Windows SDK version to ensure it meets minimum requirements.
>   [2016-09-27T16:51:04] The installed Windows SDK version is supported
>
> ### (10.0.14393.33) [2016-09-27T16:51:04]
>
> Initializing AppxManifest.xml
>
> [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Creating working directory structure at
>   C:\DesktopAppConverter\4e2c2695-d2df-4384-b4e7-27b2a8f5e93d
>   [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Attempting to set appx manifest property
>   'PackageName' to 'TestTest'. [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Attempting to set
>   appx manifest property 'Publisher' to 'CN=Test'.
>   [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Attempting to set appx manifest property
>   'Version' to '0.0.0.1'. [2016-09-27T16:51:04] No value provided for
>   appx manifest property 'PackagePublisherDisplayName'. Attempting to
>   set it to the default value 'CN=Test'
>   [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Attempting to set appx manifest property
>   'PackagePublisherDisplayName' to 'CN=Test'. [2016-09-27T16:51:04]
>   No value provided for appx manifest property 'PackageDisplayName'.
>   Attempting to set it to the default value 'TestTest'
>   [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Attempting to set appx manifest property
>   'PackageDisplayName' to 'TestTest'. [2016-09-27T16:51:04] No value
>   provided for appx manifest property 'AppDescription'. Attempting to
>   set it to the default value 'TestTest' [2016-09-27T16:51:04]
>   Attempting to set appx manifest property 'AppDescription' to
>   'TestTest'. [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Attempting to set appx manifest
>   property 'AppDisplayName' to 'TestTest'. [2016-09-27T16:51:04] No
>   value provided for appx manifest property 'AppId'. Attempting to set
>   it to the default value 'TestTest' [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Attempting to
>   set appx manifest property 'AppId' to 'TestTest'.
>
> ### [2016-09-27T16:51:04]
>
> Validating Input
>
> [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Expanded base image(s) found at
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images. Attempting to choose the most
>   recent one compatible with your version of Windows.
>   [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Testing if expanded base image at
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393 is compatible
>   with your OS [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Your Windows version was determined
>   to be 10.0.14393.0 [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Attempting to determine
>   Windows version for expanded base image at
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393
>   [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Attempting to determine version from version
>   file
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393\version.json
>   if it exists [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Version found in
>   'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393\version.json'
>   is: 10.0.14393.0 [2016-09-27T16:51:04]
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393 is of windows
>   version 10.0.14393.0 [2016-09-27T16:51:04] The expanded base image
>   version was determined to be 10.0.14393.0 [2016-09-27T16:51:04]
>   Ignoring revision numbers [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Expanded base image at
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393 IS compatible
>   with your OS [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Expanded base image with compatible
>   Windows version found:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393
>   [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Using expanded base image:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393
>   [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Checking that the ExpandedBaseImage
>   'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393' is valid
>   [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Testing if expanded base image at
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393 is compatible
>   with your OS [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Your Windows version was determined
>   to be 10.0.14393.0 [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Attempting to determine
>   Windows version for expanded base image at
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393
>   [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Attempting to determine version from version
>   file
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393\version.json
>   if it exists [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Version found in
>   'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393\version.json'
>   is: 10.0.14393.0 [2016-09-27T16:51:04]
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393 is of windows
>   version 10.0.14393.0 [2016-09-27T16:51:04] The expanded base image
>   version was determined to be 10.0.14393.0 [2016-09-27T16:51:04]
>   Ignoring revision numbers [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Expanded base image at
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393 IS compatible
>   with your OS [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Attempting to determine Windows
>   version for expanded base image at
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393
>   [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Attempting to determine version from version
>   file
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393\version.json
>   if it exists [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Version found in
>   'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393\version.json'
>   is: 10.0.14393.0 [2016-09-27T16:51:04]
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393 is of windows
>   version 10.0.14393.0 [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Ensuring the provided
>   Installer (C:\my\Test1.exe) exists [2016-09-27T16:51:04] Checking
>   if Destination (c:\temp\TEST1) exists [2016-09-27T16:51:04]
>   c:\temp\TEST1 exists [2016-09-27T16:51:04] c:\temp\TEST1 exists but is
>   not empty [2016-09-27T16:51:05] Moving files currently at
>   'c:\temp\TEST1' to 'c:\temp\TEST1.old0' [2016-09-27T16:51:05] Ensuring
>   that this script has write permissions to c:\temp\TEST1...
>   [2016-09-27T16:51:05] Checking that installer is not sibling to
>
> ### working directory [2016-09-27T16:51:05]
>
> Setting up Conversion Environment
>
> [2016-09-27T16:51:05] Copying contents of C:\tq to
>   C:\DesktopAppConverter\4e2c2695-d2df-4384-b4e7-27b2a8f5e93d\shared\installer
>   to be shared with isolated environment [2016-09-27T16:51:05] Copying
>   KnownFolderDump.exe and its dependencies to
>   C:\DesktopAppConverter\4e2c2695-d2df-4384-b4e7-27b2a8f5e93d\shared\dac\bin
>
> ### [2016-09-27T16:51:05]
>
> Running Installer in Isolated Environment
>
> [2016-09-27T16:51:05] No installer valid exit codes specified. Using
>   defaults: 0 [2016-09-27T16:51:05] Replace any occurence of
>    in -InstallerArguments with C:\shared\logs
>   [2016-09-27T16:51:05] Creating Isolated Environment
>   [2016-09-27T16:51:06] Starting the Isolated Environment
>   [2016-09-27T16:53:07] An error occurred running your installer in
>   isolation [2016-09-27T16:53:07] Invoke-IsolatedInstall : error
>   'E_STARTING_ISOLATED_ENV_FAILED': Failed to start the isolated
>   environment. See inner exception for more details.
>   [2016-09-27T16:53:07] Disposing of the Isolated Environment
>   [2016-09-27T16:53:07] Moving any logs in
>   C:\DesktopAppConverter\4e2c2695-d2df-4384-b4e7-27b2a8f5e93d\shared\logs
>   to C:\DesktopAppConverter\4e2c2695-d2df-4384-b4e7-27b2a8f5e93d\logs
>   [2016-09-27T16:53:07] Moving any dac output in
>   C:\DesktopAppConverter\4e2c2695-d2df-4384-b4e7-27b2a8f5e93d\shared\dac\out
>   to
>   C:\DesktopAppConverter\4e2c2695-d2df-4384-b4e7-27b2a8f5e93d\output\dac
>   [2016-09-27T16:53:07] Cleaning up by removing isolated environment
>   shared folder
>   C:\DesktopAppConverter\4e2c2695-d2df-4384-b4e7-27b2a8f5e93d\shared
>   [2016-09-27T16:53:07] An error occurred converting your application.
>   Here is the full error record:  [2016-09-27T16:53:07]
>
> PowerShell Error Record: DesktopAppConverter : error
>   'E_STARTING_ISOLATED_ENV_FAILED': Failed to start the isolated
>   environment. See inner exception for more details.
>   [2016-09-27T16:53:07]  PowerShell Stack Trace: at RaiseUserException,
>   C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_1.0.0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\converter_util\DACLogger.ps1:
>   line 151 at Invoke-IsolatedInstall, C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_1.0.0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\converter_util\IsolatedEnvironmentOps.ps1: line 153 at , C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_1.0.0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\DesktopAppConverter.ps1:
>   line 465 at , : line 1 [2016-09-27T16:53:07]
>
> Inner Exception[0]: System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException:
>   DesktopAppConverter : error 'E_STARTING_ISOLATED_ENV_FAILED': Failed
>   to start the isolated environment. See inner exception for more
>   details. ---> System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException:
>   Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "One or more errors
>   occurred." ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurred. ---> Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsException:
>   HCS function call returned error. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: This operation returned
>   because the timeout period expired. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x800705B4)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.ProcessHcsCall(Int32
>   resultCode, String result)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.IHcs.StartComputeSystem(IntPtr
>   computeSystem, String options)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.Start()    at
>   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext
>   funcContext, Exception exception)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext
>   funcContext, Exception exception)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame) [2016-09-27T16:53:07]  Inner Exception Stack Trace[0]    at
>   System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext
>   funcContext, Exception exception)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame) [2016-09-27T16:53:07]
>
> Inner Exception[1]:
>   System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception
>   calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "One or more errors occurred."
>   ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsException: HCS function
>   call returned error. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   This operation returned because the timeout period expired. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x800705B4)    --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   ---    at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.ProcessHcsCall(Int32
>   resultCode, String result)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.IHcs.StartComputeSystem(IntPtr
>   computeSystem, String options)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.Start()    at
>   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext
>   funcContext, Exception exception)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame) [2016-09-27T16:53:07]  Inner Exception Stack Trace[1]    at
>   System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext
>   funcContext, Exception exception)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame) [2016-09-27T16:53:07]
>
> Inner Exception[2]: System.AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurred. ---> Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsException:
>   HCS function call returned error. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: This operation returned
>   because the timeout period expired. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x800705B4)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.ProcessHcsCall(Int32
>   resultCode, String result)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.IHcs.StartComputeSystem(IntPtr
>   computeSystem, String options)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.Start()    at
>   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsException: HCS function
>   call returned error. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   This operation returned because the timeout period expired. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x800705B4)    --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   ---    at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.ProcessHcsCall(Int32
>   resultCode, String result)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.IHcs.StartComputeSystem(IntPtr
>   computeSystem, String options)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.d__8.MoveNext()<---
>
> [2016-09-27T16:53:07]  Inner Exception Stack Trace[2]    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.Start()    at
>   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object ) [2016-09-27T16:53:07]
>
> Inner Exception[3]:
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsException: HCS function
>   call returned error. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   This operation returned because the timeout period expired. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x800705B4)    --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   ---    at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.ProcessHcsCall(Int32
>   resultCode, String result)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.IHcs.StartComputeSystem(IntPtr
>   computeSystem, String options)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.d__8.MoveNext()
>   [2016-09-27T16:53:07]  Inner Exception Stack Trace[3]    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.ProcessHcsCall(Int32
>   resultCode, String result)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.IHcs.StartComputeSystem(IntPtr
>   computeSystem, String options)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.d__8.MoveNext()
>   [2016-09-27T16:53:07]
>
> Inner Exception[4]: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x800705B4): This operation returned because the timeout period
>   expired. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800705B4) [2016-09-27T16:53:07]
>   The full error record is saved in the logs at
>   C:\DesktopAppConverter\4e2c2695-d2df-4384-b4e7-27b2a8f5e93d\logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason seem to be Hyper-V is not installed/available.